# Aurora Serverless alter table Error 1114 table is full

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, aws-aurora

Using Aurora Serverless, when attempting to `alter table mytable add column mynewcolumn decimal(10,3) after myoldcolumn` I receive "ERROR 1114 (HY000): The Table 'mytable' is full". The table has hundreds of millions of rows. Normally this error results from a full partition, but since I'm using Aurora Serverless, I can't manually provision partition space. What should I do to avoid this error?

Answer (score 0):

On the [AWS Forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=889929&tstart=0), LawrenceAtAWS said,

> the amount of temporary storage space associated with Serverless increases linearly with the number of associated ACUs. If you're having issues running out of temporary storage space for large table mutations, you could temporarily scale the cluster up to a larger number of ACUs and then run the modify statement. This should increase the associated temporary storage an allow the statement to succeed.

The way to achieve this with the [CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.setting-capacity.html) is
  `aws rds modify-current-db-cluster-capacity --db-cluster-identifier sample-cluster --capacity 64`